# Dot Net 6 Entity Framework Core project using Swagger is not working the way Microsoft suggests

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, swagger, asp.net-core-6.0

I am trying to get a DotNet 6 Entity Framework Core project up and running.

The new version is using something called Swagger, which sounds great because it is supposed to provide a UI to test your web API calls, but I can't get it to work.

So I created my project, got all the models setup via scaffolding. I am now adding my controllers via the Add New Scaffold Item in the controller folder.

I am choosing these options:

[image]

I also tried leaving `Use a layout page` blank, but that didn't change the outcome.

I rebuilt the project and started it up expecting to see something like this:

[image]

But it's not adding my controllers.  It just has the default weather one like this:

[image]

So I thought maybe I need to add them manually to the main view.

Well I don't think there is a main view, or at least I can't find one.  The only shared view created by Visual Studio is called:
`_ValidationScriptsPartial.cshtml`

Inside that view is just calls to external javascript libraries like this: `https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.17.0/jquery.validate.min.js`

Has anyone been able to get this to work the way it should?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you share the code of one of the controllers you added? BTW, read up on what Swagger is. Its main purpose is not ad hoc testing, but generating clients. It's been around for about a decade, and it adds so much value for API consumers that APIs without it are hard to take seriously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to set api but not view with Scaffold, you should choose `API Controller with actions, using Entity Framework`, but not `MVC Controllers with views`. And it worked for me.

[image]